# "cd" redefinition causes infinite loop in bash

Tags: bash

I redefined `cd` in my `.bashrc` to:

```
function cd() {
  builtin cd $*
  pwd
}
```

This worked for a while, until I mistyped

```
cd *2
```

as

```
cd *(2
```

When I did that, bash prompted me, I went "d'oh", and when I entered `)`, it went into an infinite loop.

So OK, I should have said `"$@"` instead of `$*` in the function definition (although I'm still not sure if I could explain why).  But why would that cause bash to transcend this earthly plane?

Comment: The difference between `$*` and `"$@"` demonstrated at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314451/accessing-bash-command-line-args-vs/12316565#12316565

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a directory named `$'2\n'` in your current directory, I don't understand it.

The syntax `*(pattern)` is an "extended globbing" pattern ([ref](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching)) that returns zero or more of the given pattern. Given your pattern (a `2` and a newline) I would expect that to return null. And then calling your function with no arguments should simply cd to your homedir.

Comment: Hi Glenn, thanks for the responses.  No, there was a directory with a name ending in 2, and that's the dir that I was trying to get to, but it actually works no matter what directory I'm in and no matter whether there is any subdir with a name ending in 2.  My teammates were able to reproduce it, once they entered the redefinition of "cd"; and I just confirmed that it doesn't matter whether the function is itself called "cd" or "gronk".  Without the definition, bash correctly gives me an error message, so it must have to do with the definition as well.